# AC3 audio not working on Mountain Lion with Perian

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, audio, video, codec

I'm developing a video application that needs to open video files encoded with different codecs.

All was working fine on Lion but recently I upgraded to Mountain Lion and AC3 (A52) audio tracks stopped working.

Is there any work around for this, ou should I wait for the promised last release of Perian?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the problem is related to the A52Codec.component from the Perian package. You can download an updated working version from my site at http://www.bitfield.se/support/index.html#1.
Any better?

Comment: Thanks, but it is not working for me. I tried to do as you suggested but with no luck. I tried to copy both to `/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Components` and `~/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Components` but couldn't make it work.